# Second level cache not working With Spring and JSF

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsf-2, ehcache

I am using **Hibernate4+Spring4.0.3.RELEASE+JSF2.0+hibernate-ehcache4.1.0Final** for my web application I have implemented second level cache in my project but it not working Here are code

**applicationContext.xml** file (Inside WEB-INF folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:ehcache="http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">


    <ehcache:annotation-driven />

    <ehcache:config cache-manager="cacheManager">
        <ehcache:evict-expired-elements
            interval="60" />
    </ehcache:config>

    <bean id="cacheManager"
        class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/ehcache.xml" />

    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ccc.spring" />

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:spring-configured />


    <!-- Data Source Declaration -->

    <bean id="DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
        <property name="user" value="user" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="2" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="1" />


    </bean>


    <!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
    <bean id="SessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />

        <property name="packagesToScan"> <list> <value>com.ccc.spring.model</value> 
            </list> </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
                </prop>


                <!--useful for debugging -->
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <!-- <property name="loadTimeWeaver"> <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" 
            /> </property> <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="danielme_persistenceunit" 
            /> -->

    </bean>

    <!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

    <!-- Transaction Manager is defined -->
    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**ehcache.xml** file(Inside WEB-INF folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache>

    <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="100" eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="20000" />
    <cache name="ValidUserRole" maxElementsInMemory="100"
        eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="5" timeToLiveSeconds="20000" />
```

In DAO file i am using below code

```
 @Cacheable( value = "ValidUserRole" )
    public List<Validuserrole> getRoleList() {
        List list = null;
        try{
          list = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("from Validuserrole ").list();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

but when i am debugging code its fetch data from DB everytime not taking from second level cache

Comment: Why aren't you using Springs own caching support? Also what you want isn't second level caching but result caching. Second level cache is a ORM provider thing (in this case hibernate).

Comment: So its not the way to used second level cache if not what you can suggest some better option?

Comment: The point is you aer mixing, query caching, second level caching and springs (or spring-ehcache) caching support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing 2 different things [hibernates second level caching](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-cache) and [Springs caching support](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html), those are two different beasts. You are trying to mix both of them. What makes it worse is that you are trying to use [Spring-Ehcache](https://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/) which is basically the predecessor of Springs own caching support.

***Caching Method Results***

For starters remove the spring-ehcache stuff and switch to the [spring provided caching support](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html). This should make the `@Cacheable` annotation work. If that is what you want, instead of second level caching you are done.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"      
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<cache:annotation-driven />

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
    <constructor-arg ref="ehcacheManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="ehcacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/ehcache.xml" />
</bean>
```

**Note:** It is also suggested to use versionless xsd files, this way you ensure that you always use schema files which belong to your Spring version.

***Second Level Caching***

For second level caching to work you have to understand how it works, first your entity has to be [cacheable](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-cache-mapping) if that isn't the case nothing is going to be cached.

```
@Entity
@Cacheable // Note this is from hibernate NOT spring!!!
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Validuserrole { ... }
```

Next the query will be executed however the resulting objects, when cacheable, will be held in memory. Then for the next time the same entity instance is needed the one from the cache will be returned.

***Query Caching***

If you want to enable query caching you have to make [the query cacheable](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-querycache) else it won't be cached.

```
list = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery("from Validuserrole ")
            .setCacheable(true)
            .list();
```

Comment: Do you mean i do not need <ehcache:annotation-driven />

 <ehcache:config cache-manager="cacheManager">
  <ehcache:evict-expired-elements
   interval="60" />
 </ehcache:config>

Also you added <cache:annotation-driven /> and remove ehcache tags?

Comment: Correct, that is already in your `ehcache.xml` and next to that the `<ehcache />` stuff (the spring-ehcache project) has been dead since 2011 (after that Spring introduced its own caching abstracting). Also that doesn't do anything for second level caching as those 2 things are unrelated.

Comment: So still something missing i am getting Failed to convert property value of type 'net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager' to required type 'org.springframework.cache.CacheManager' for property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager] to required type [org.springframework.cache.CacheManager] for property 'cacheManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Comment: My bad, missed a bean. See modified answer.

Comment: Thanks Brother working like charm.Another question will this is best approach which used above or it we will be good we create our own implementation for cache and refresh cache data time to time when we needed Please guide me?Actully I have Valid table and i want when Server will start all data should be load in cache and then i will use that data and it will refresh automatically every 24hours.

Comment: Also i think no need of this code <cache name="ValidUserRole" maxElementsInMemory="100"
  eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="5" timeToLiveSeconds="20000" />

Comment: That depends if you want a specific cache configuration for the `ValidUserRole` cache or not.

Comment: Can you answer my previous question as well

Comment: That is basically already answered you need to configure your cache properly. i.e. how long is the cache valid etc. that is all configurable. I strongly suggst you read on how ehcache works and how you can configure it.